# Why is there an $a_0$ term in Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series

[Fourier Series Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zjpe.png)

I get the reason why the Fourier Series sums up the sine and cosine function, but I do not understand what the purpose of the $a_0$ in the front? Is the $a_0$ there in case the original $f(x)$ function does not go through $(0, 0)$. I am no math genius so I am sorry if this a stupid question

Comment: $a_0$ represents the zero-frequency $a_0 \cos(0x) = a_0$.  We could also try to add a term for $b_0 \sin(0x)$, but that would always be equal to zero so it would be pointless to include.

Answer (score 6):

For periodic sine and cosine functions, the average value of the function over a period is zero. i.e.
$$\frac 1T\int_T \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}T x\right)dx=0$$
This means if the fourier series of a function is totally expressed in terms of pure sine and cosine functions, then its average value is zero. But sometimes we have a periodic function whose average value is not zero. For example:

[image: wave]

So here comes the mighty $a_0$ to get rid of that bias and express the rest of function in terms of sines and cosines.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right; you might find it an enlightening exercise to try and work out what would the Fourier series of $x \mapsto 1$ would be if you weren't allowed access to the $n=0$ term of the cosine expansion.

Answer (score 0):

$b_{n} sin(nx) + a_{n} cos(nx)$ put $n = 0$.

Comment: I have never seen negative indices used for the sine coefficients of a Fourier series.  From where does this convention originate?

Comment: @ErickWong: Let's not be mean, it's obviously a typo: on standard US keyboards "_" (used for lower indices) is on the same key as "-", so here it seems that both symbols have been input by mistake.

Comment: edited. Thanks @ErickWong

Comment: @AlexM.  It wasn't *obviously* a typo to me, and I was genuinely curious.  I could very easily imagine some author, perhaps in an applied field, saying "let's take two sets of coefficients, one indexed by $\mathbb Z^{\ge 0}$ and the other indexed by $\mathbb Z^{>0}$, and merge them into one coefficient set indexed by $\mathbb Z$ by negating one of them".  There is an attractive parsimony in that arrangement, even though it makes for a non-uniform definition of coefficients.

Comment: in Engineering!